# OCaml appending two lists

Tags: list, ocaml

I know it seems like a basic question but I need help appending list s2 to list s1. 
I've tried using the append function but I get an error saying:

> unbound value append

Here's my code:

```
let s1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
let s2 = [6; 7; 8; 9; 10];;
let s3 = append s1 s2;;
```

I've looked all over the internet to fix this simple problem and found nothing, so please if you know how to help, do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've opened the `List` module, which you shouldn't, you'll have to qualify it with the module:

```ml
let s3 = List.append s1 s2;;
```

Alternatively there's also the `@` operator:

```ml
let s3 = s1 @ s2;;
```